# How to let user select currency in Django using Django-money?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am currently working on an online store. I want a user to be able to change their currency option in the header and convert the whole site to the currency choice. I have found app called django-money, which seams to have that functionality, but I cannot find any implementation examples.

I want it to work like localize work in django. Having a form that will redirect to URL and saving choice in session and in cookie. This is the example of the language selection code.

```
/template.html
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
      <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit()">
         {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
         {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
         {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
         {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                          {{ language.code|upper}}
            </option>
         {% endfor %}
      </select>
   </form>
```

And then whenever I need something to be translated I will use this inside html:

```
{% trans "Some text to translate" %}
```

So is there something similar for currency? What would be the action for the form? Please can somebody help if you have ready solution! I will really appreciate.

Comment: You should add the link to the django-money project: https://github.com/django-money/django-money